# Remove My billing and shipping address are the same checkbox in Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation

I want to hide the checkbox and message at the checkout that shows the message :

```
My billing and shipping addresse are the same
```

Without effecting the checkout procees. I wanto to remove it.

I tried to remove this div:

```
   <div class="billing-address-same-as-shipping-block field choice" data-bind="visible: canUseShippingAddress()">
        <input type="checkbox" name="billing-address-same-as-shipping"
               data-bind="checked: isAddressSameAsShipping, click: useShippingAddress, attr: {id: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {for: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping-' + getCode($parent)}"><span
                data-bind="i18n: 'My billing and shipping address are the same'"></span></label>
    </div>
```

in the vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address.html

It hides the message and checkbox on pacling the order it shows me the error
as :

[image]

Comment: It not hides, it have been remove because you remove the code so that why you getting this error. If you want to hides, you should use css for hide it. Try the answer of @Ahmad

Answer (score 0):

You're encountering this issue because even though you've removed the checkbox, the underlying JavaScript and backend logic still expect that data to be present.

The safer approach would be to hide the checkbox and the message using CSS rather than modifying the code directly.

1. You can add this CSS rule to your custom theme CSS file:

```
.billing-address-same-as-shipping-block {
    display: none !important;
}
```

2. Or, if you want to use a layout XML update (in your theme's Magento_Checkout layout override), you can do it like this:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .billing-address-same-as-shipping-block {
            display: none !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

This way, the functionality remains intact, but the checkbox and the message are hidden from the user.

Remember that hiding the checkbox will automatically mean that the billing address will always be the same as the shipping address. Ensure that this is the behavior you want.

Comment: And this is not show us the error message in the picture I shared on placing the order

Answer (score 0):

To hide the "My billing and shipping address are the same" checkbox on the checkout page in Magento 2, you can follow these steps:

1. Go to your Magento theme directory.
2. Locate the file: Magento_Checkout/web/template/billing-address.html.
3. Override this file in your theme.
4. Add the following code in the overridden file:

   ```
   <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Checkout/billing-address/details' --><!-- /ko -->
   <fieldset class="fieldset" data-bind="visible: !isAddressDetailsVisible()">
       <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Checkout/billing-address/list' --><!-- /ko -->
       <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Checkout/billing-address/form' --><!-- /ko -->
       <div class="actions-toolbar">
           <div class="primary">
               <button class="action action-update" type="button" data-bind="click: updateAddress">
                   <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
               </button>
               <button class="action action-cancel" type="button" data-bind="click: cancelAddressEdit">
                   <span data-bind="i18n: 'Cancel'"></span>
               </button>
           </div>
       </div>
   </fieldset>
   ```

After then run the following commands :

- php bin/magento s:up;
- php bin/magento s:d:c;
- php bin/magento s:s:d -f;
- php bin/magneto c:f